# jQuery custom function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Alright so Ive got a problem, well more like a question than a problem to be honest.

What Im trying to achieve is simple, but I dont understand how to do it.

Im trying to make a custom function in jQuery but I dont get it how I should do it?
I tried a way with like

```
function MyFunction(VarName[]) {
        var vaz;
        switch(VarName) {
            case "Test": vaz = "Hello";;
        }
        return Alert(vaz);
}


$(".Something").click(function() {
        MyFunction("Test");

});
```

But of course that doesnt work. Its just an example code tho, so yeah, how do I achieve this?

Comment: in function parameter you have varname as array but when the click event  trigger you send string as parameter. change varname[] to varname

Comment: Change `VarName[]` to just `VarName`, and `return Alert` to just `alert`. It should work ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".Something").click(function() {
        MyFunction("Test");

});

function MyFunction(VarName) {
        var vaz;
        switch(VarName) {
            case "Test": 
            vaz = "Hello";
            break;
        }
        alert(vaz);
}
```

You are set the parameter as array in function and you are sending string value , change the parameter to string.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Add your javascript here
$(function(){
function MyFunction(VarName) {
        var vaz;
        switch(VarName) {
            case "Test": vaz = "Hello";;
        }
        return alert(vaz);
}


$(".Something").click(function() {
        MyFunction("Test");

});
});
```

the alert is wrong its not ALert its alert and also r passing the function wrong VarName[]  , u have to pass only VarName for refrence https://plnkr.co/edit/etSEQOcf6OeiZiDyIZN2?p=preview